# Not being able to grab element by ID using $(this)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, this

I'm not sure why but when I try to run this function:

```
$(this).click(function(){
    setArroPos($(this));
});
```

Which is defined by:

```
function setArroPos($element){
    var selector = $("#selector");
    var primeiraPos = parseFloat($("#selector").css("left"))
    var leftOffSet = 0;
    var curent = 0;
    var newValue;

    alert($element.attr("id"));

    switch($element.attr("id")){
        case '#tratamento-imagem':
            newValue = primeiraPos;
            break;
        case '#portfolio':
            leftOffSet = $("#portfolio").outerWidth(true);
            curent = parseFloat(selector.css("left"));
            newValue = leftOffSet+curent;
            break;
        case '#fotografia':
            leftOffSet = $("#fotografia").outerWidth(true);
            curent = parseFloat(selector.css("left"));
            newValue = leftOffSet+curent;
            break;
        case '#montagem':
            newValue = ($("#thumb-services").width()) - primeiraPos;
            break;
    }

    selector.animate({left: newValue+'px'});
}
```

The alert outputs "Undefined" for the ID. What I want to do is grab the ID of any element I click and then compare then to the cases in the switch statement in order to define how far should an arrow in my site go. All the elements I clicked had an ID so it's not giving me "Undefined" because I was clicking on a element with no ID.

Here is the relevant HTML:

```
    <nav id="thumb-services">
        <a id="tratamento-imagem" class="menu-item">
            <div class="hover-menu">
                <p class="menu-p"> Tratamento de Imagem </p>
            </div>
        </a>
        <a id="portfolio" class="menu-item">
            <div class="hover-menu">
                <p class="menu-p"> Pós Produção </p>
            </div>
        </a>
        <a id="fotografia" class="menu-item">
            <div class="hover-menu">
                <p class="menu-p"> Fotografia </p>
            </div>
        </a>
        <a id="montagem" class="menu-item">
            <div class="hover-menu">
                <p class="menu-p"> Portifólio </p>
            </div>
        </a>    
    </nav>
    <div id="main-info">
        <div id="selector"></div>
        <div id="panel">
            <p id="teste">Hello world!</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: And where is `$(this).click` being set/called? We need to see that code!

Comment: why not have everything in `setArroPos` be in moved to be directly inside the `click` event?

Comment: Indeed, where come the `$(this)` from in the click setter? It would be fairly simple to conclude that the element doesn't have an id set to it.

Comment: It being called one the document is ready, here is the code: `$(document).ready(function () { $(this).click(function(){
     setArroPos($(this));
    });
});`

Comment: Because you just added a click handler to the window and the window does not have an id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe to get this to work you need to change this:

```
$(this).click(function(){
    setArroPos($(this));
});
```

to:

```
$("a.menu-item").click(function(){
    setArroPos($(this));
});
```

The `$(this)` in your current code is most likely referring to the `window` object and that object doesn't have an id attribute set.

Example:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("a.menu-item").click(function(){
      setArroPos($(this));
  });
});


function setArroPos($element){
    var selector = $("#selector");
    var primeiraPos = parseFloat($("#selector").css("left"))
    var leftOffSet = 0;
    var curent = 0;
    var newValue;

    alert($element.attr("id"));

    switch($element.attr("id")){
        case '#tratamento-imagem':
            newValue = primeiraPos;
            break;
        case '#portfolio':
            leftOffSet = $("#portfolio").outerWidth(true);
            curent = parseFloat(selector.css("left"));
            newValue = leftOffSet+curent;
            break;
        case '#fotografia':
            leftOffSet = $("#fotografia").outerWidth(true);
            curent = parseFloat(selector.css("left"));
            newValue = leftOffSet+curent;
            break;
        case '#montagem':
            newValue = ($("#thumb-services").width()) - primeiraPos;
            break;
    }

    selector.animate({left: newValue+'px'});
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id="thumb-services">
        <a id="tratamento-imagem" class="menu-item">
            <div class="hover-menu">
                <p class="menu-p"> Tratamento de Imagem </p>
            </div>
        </a>
        <a id="portfolio" class="menu-item">
            <div class="hover-menu">
                <p class="menu-p"> Pós Produção </p>
            </div>
        </a>
        <a id="fotografia" class="menu-item">
            <div class="hover-menu">
                <p class="menu-p"> Fotografia </p>
            </div>
        </a>
        <a id="montagem" class="menu-item">
            <div class="hover-menu">
                <p class="menu-p"> Portifólio </p>
            </div>
        </a>    
    </nav>
    <div id="main-info">
        <div id="selector"></div>
        <div id="panel">
            <p id="teste">Hello world!</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks Mouser, you were right... now it is working :)

Comment: Glad to be of service.